# Launch first system or second depending on whether key combination is pressed

Tags: linux, boot, keyboard

Is this possible to launch first system or second depending on whether key combination is pressed? For example, I have Windows and Linux. I can choose which one I want to launch using GRUB. Is this possible to boot Windows only when particular key combination is pressed during boot? Eg. `CTRL+~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if GRUB2 can use keyboard shortcuts at boot time to select boot entries.

In Windows 7/8 there is a mechanism called "[custom bootstrap actions](http://www.boyans.net/CustomActions.html)" which allows assigning keys or key combinations to boot entries.

If you use MBR booting you can [setup you system so that Windows boot manager controls the booting
of both Windows 7/8 and Linux](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html).

On UEFI/GPT Windows 7/8 boot manager cannot boot directly foreign OS.